# Underground Power Cable Cut By Bucket Of An Small Excavator

Tags: electrical

Can someone please explain to me how an underground power cable cut by a bucket of a small excavator causes a power surge into my house destroying appliances? Is it with the neutral and earth wires come into contact?

Comment: Do you know he voltage of the line?

Comment: Was this line the service to your house, a feeder to your house, a feeder to an outbuilding, a branch circuit to some outdoor light or outlet, or one of the power company's wires?

Comment: Hindsight 20/20 of course, but curious anyway: Was this "Called utility to mark things and dug in the wrong place?" or "Didn't bother to call utility?" or "Called utility but marking was done wrong?"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need to know more in order to help you.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that at some point during the cut, one of the phases was shorted to the neutral;  when that happens, the line to neutral voltage in the house will be 240V rather than the usual 120V, which is enough to do some damage.

It is not likely that shorting neutral to ground would cause any trouble at all.  The neutral is bonded to ground both at your service and at the pole - that's normal.

Answer (score 0):

If it severs neutral, but not the hots -- it will create a "Lost Neutral" situation.

Your power comes as 2 poles of 240V, with a neutral in the middle. Tapping a pole and neutral gives 120V *in theory*.

Some of your 120V circuits are on one pole.  Others are on the other pole.

If you lose the neutral wire, you still have the two poles, and they still *add up to* 240V.  However, **neutral is no longer in the middle**.  That means one side is *less than* 120V, and the other side is *equally more than* 120V.

And this will shift as loads come on and off. The lesser loaded pole will have the higher voltage, and that's what damages appliances.

Comment: Is there not also the issue with monentary shorts on a power line when eventually removed can cause an over voltage surge as the line tries to recover to normal operating voltage??